# Duplicate Excel graph line using epplus

Tags: excel, epplus

I am editing an existing excel file using `epplus`. The excel file consists of several sheets and in one of the sheets I have a graph that is pointing to the data in the other sheets.

Next, I have duplicated one of the data sheets (say sheet A) to another (sheet B). I want to update my graph and add a line to it that points to sheet B. I don't know in which column the data is. My idea is to get this information from the graph line corresponding to sheet A's data.

I can find the `serie` corresponding to sheet A but I can not see where the information about columns are.

How can one extract this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after not getting an answer on this, I hacked it by reflection and getting the underlying private field. It is not what I would want to do but it fixes my problem for now.

In this example the `oldSheetName` is the sheet that I want to copy its line. I hope this helps someone some day.

```
foreach (ExcelChartSerie serie in chart.Series)
{
    if (!serie.HeaderAddress.Address.Contains(oldSheetName)) continue;

    FieldInfo property = serie.GetType().GetField("_node", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    XmlNode node = property.GetValue(serie) as XmlNode;

    string xval = node["c:xVal"]?["c:numRef"]?["c:f"]?.InnerText
                                              .Replace(oldSheetName + "!", "").Replace("$", "") ?? "";

    string yval = node["c:yVal"]?["c:numRef"]?["c:f"]?.InnerText
                                              .Replace(oldSheetName + "!", "").Replace("$", "") ?? "";

    var newSerie = chart.Series.Add(newSheet.Cells[xval], newSheet.Cells[yval]);

    newSerie.HeaderAddress = new ExcelAddress(serie.HeaderAddress.Address.Replace(oldSheetName, newSheet.Name));

    break;

}
```